# Knowing if a directory is modified

Tags: files, directory

I have a server online and I am wondering if there's a way to know if some file on the server is modified or a new file is added to certain directories.

For example, I have this public_html/myblog/files

this directory contains several files. What I want is to be notified by email if one of the current files inside that directory is modified or if a new file is added to that directory. If possible to receiving a message telling me what files are new or were modified.

Is this possible? I am using CentOS 6.8

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `dnotify` or `inotify` see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) .

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862346/check-if-the-directory-content-has-changed-with-shell-script-or-python) stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

Tripwire is what you're looking for.  Check this post: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2006-June/023655.html

Tripwire will email you if a file or directory that is configured to be watched changes.